# How to update data in Laravel - there is array value in data

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, api

There is field affiliated_facility which is in array and I am trying to update my values:

My controller code:

```
<?php
$affiliated_facility = implode(",", $userProfile['affiliated_facility']);
$userBasicInfoId = UserBasicInfo::where('user_id', $userProfile['id'])->value('id')->update([

    'work_phone' => $userProfile['work_phone'],
    'fax' => $userProfile['fax'],
    'extension' => $userProfile['extension'],
    'primary_facility' => $userProfile['primary_facility'],
    'employed_by' => $userProfile['employed_by'],
    'emergency_phone' => $userProfile['emergency_phone'],
    'designation' => $userProfile['designation'],
    'department' => $userProfile['department'],
    'employment_type' => $userProfile['employment_type'],
    'biography' => $userProfile['biography'],
    'hiring_date' => $userProfile['hiring_date'],
    'from' => $userProfile['from'],
    'to' => $userProfile['to'],
    'affiliated_facility' => $affiliated_facility]);   // this is in array so I used implode in top of this code

if ($userBasicInfoId) {
    $userBasicInfo = $this->userBasicInfo->find($userBasicInfoId);
    $userBasicInfo->fill($userProfile)->save();
} else {
    $userBasicInfo = $this->userBasicInfo->create($request->only($this->userBasicInfo->getModel()->fillable));
}
?>
```

But when  I hit my request it says

> Call to a member function update() on integer

There is some mistakes in my code. I want to update my record and there is one field coming which is in array:

```
"affiliated_facility": [1,2]
```

How can I modify this code?

Comment: I think the problem is in `->value('id')->update` - why the `->value('id')` is for?

Comment: to update the record against "id" this id is primary key

Comment: But that is why the `where('user_id', $userProfile['id'])` is for

Comment: if i remove ->value('id) then it says Call to a member function fill() on null

Comment: @syed1234 it could be that $userProfile['id'] doeasn't exist in table or it is empty,

Comment: id exist in database i checked

Comment: @syed1234 `id` or `user_id`?

Comment: what is the database affiliated_facility type you defined?

Answer (score 0):

`UserBasicInfo::where('user_id', $userProfile['id'])` is a **Builder** instance. you should get **Model** instance to update it. So, try:

```
 UserBasicInfo::where('user_id', $userProfile['id'])->first()->update([...]);
```

Comment: I tried this but it says Call to a member function fill() on null

Comment: then show us what you see when you try to dd(UserBasicInfo::where('user_id', $userProfile['id'])->first())